# Extracting part of line between two words

Tags: sed, line, cpu-word

I want to extract all word between two word in a line

for example: 1.word: p520-653DBBE  2.word: Server-9406-525-SN6582290

```
root@aixv71(/tmp/murat)$ cat test.txt 
p520-653DBBE hacmpn1 hacmpn2 NIMSERVER GPFSNODE2 GPFSNODE1 VIOS1 Server-9406-525-SN6582290     montofon TIVHOSTI_AIX TIVHOSTH_AIX TIVHOSTG_AIX TIVHOSTF_AIX TIVHOSTE_AIX TIVHOSTD TIVHOST8 TIVHOST7 TIVHOSTC TIVHOSTB TIVHOSTA TIVHOST6 TIVHOST9 65-82290 P520-653DBAE aixv71 VIOS2 hacmpnode2 hacmpnode1 VIOS1 Server-9406-520-SN10EA9CC test
```

For Example: if I give 1.word: p520-653DBBE  2.word: Server-9406-525-SN6582290 
I want to see only "hacmpn1 hacmpn2 NIMSERVER GPFSNODE2 GPFSNODE1 VIOS1"

I tried too many way which stated in web

```
sed -n "/p520-653DBBE/,/Server-9406-525-SN6582290/p"

sed -e '1,/p520-653DBBE/ s/#.*//' -e '/Server-9406-525-SN6582290/,$ s/#.*//'

sed 's/p520-653DBBE\(.*\)Server-9406-525-SN6582290/\1/g'
```

... but they didn't work.

Thank you for help.

Murat.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 's/p520-653DBBE/\n/;s/Server-9406-525-SN6582290/\n/;s/.*\n (.*) \n.*/\1/p' file
```

This puts a marker either side of the intended string and extracts the string.

N.B. This extracts the shortest match

```
sed -nr 's/^.*p520-653DBBE(.*)Server-9406-525-SN6582290.*$/\1/p' file
```

may fall foul of greed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach doesn't work because using the `,` selects lines between and including the matching patterns, not text within a line.

Your third approach almost works but the regex has to match the whole line to be sure that only the replacement text is printed rather than the replacement text and some part of the original text in the line.

Thus, the following script works for me:

```
$ sed 's/^.*p520-653DBBE\(.*\)Server-9406-525-SN6582290.*$/\1/' <test.txt
 hacmpn1 hacmpn2 NIMSERVER GPFSNODE2 GPFSNODE1 VIOS1
```

(EDIT)

As pointed out by @potong, if the string `Server-9406-525-SN6582290` appears more than once on a line, `\(.*\)` will match all but the last instance of `Server-9406-525-SN6582290` as well as everything before that last instance, back to `p520-653DBBE`. The more sophisticated approach suggested by @potong deals with this "greedy" problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll chip in a 3rd answer using grep

`grep -Po '(?<=p520-653DBBE).*(?=Server-9406-525-SN6582290)' test.txt`

Note about `grep -P`

```
-P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl regular expression.  This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.
```